# difflib python formatting

Tags: python, csv

I am using this code to find difference between two csv list and hove some formatting questions. This is probably an easy fix, but I am new and trying to learn and having alot of problems.

```
 import difflib

 diff=difflib.ndiff(open('test1.csv',"rb").readlines(), open('test2.csv',"rb").readlines()) 

 try:
  while 1:
    print diff.next(),
except:
 pass
```

the code works fine and I get the output I am looking for as:

```
 Group,Symbol,Total

 - Adam,apple,3850

 ?           ^
 + Adam,apple,2850

 ?           ^
 bob,orange,-45

 bob,lemon,66

 bob,appl,-56

 bob,,88
```

My question is how do I clean the formatting up, can I make the Group,Symbol,Total into sperate columns, and the line up the text below?

Also can i change the ? to represent a text I determine? such as test 1 and test 2 representing which sheet it comes from?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 5):

Using [`difflib.unified_diff`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.unified_diff) gives much cleaner output, see below.

Also, both `difflib.ndiff` and `difflib.unified_diff` return a [Differ](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ) object that is a [generator](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator) object, which you can directly use in a for loop, and that knows when to quit, so you don't have to handle exceptions yourself. N.B; The comma after `line` is to prevent `print` from adding another newline.

```
import difflib
s1 = ['Adam,apple,3850\n', 'bob,orange,-45\n', 'bob,lemon,66\n', 
      'bob,appl,-56\n', 'bob,,88\n']
s2 = ['Adam,apple,2850\n', 'bob,orange,-45\n', 'bob,lemon,66\n', 
      'bob,appl,-56\n', 'bob,,88\n']

for line in difflib.unified_diff(s1, s2, fromfile='test1.csv',
                 tofile='test2.csv'): 
    print line,
```

This gives:

```
--- test1.csv
+++ test2.csv
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-Adam,apple,3850
+Adam,apple,2850
 bob,orange,-45
 bob,lemon,66
 bob,appl,-56
```

So you can clearly see which lines were changed between `test1.csv` and `test1.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

To line up the columns, you must use string formatting.

E.g. `print "%-20s %-20s %-20s" % (row[0],row[1],row[2])`.

To change the `?` into any text test you like, you'd use `s.replace('any text i like')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has more to do with the CSV format, since `difflib` has no idea it's looking at columnar fields. What you need is to figure out into which field the guide is pointing, so that you can adjust it when printing the columns.

If your CSV files are *simple*, i.e. they don't contain any quoted fields with embedded commas or (shudder) newlines, you can just use `split(',')` to separate them into fields, and figure out where the guide points as follows:

```
def align(line, guideline):
    """
    Figure out which field the guide (^) points to, and the offset within it.
    E.g., if the guide points 3 chars into field 2, return (2, 3)
    """
    fields = line.split(',')
    guide = guideline.index('^')
    f = p = 0
    while p + len(fields[f]) < guide:
        p += len(fields[f]) + 1     # +1 for the comma
        f += 1
    offset = guide - p
    return f, offset
```

Now it's easy to show the guide properly. Let's say you want to align your columns by printing everything 12 spaces wide:

```
diff=difflib.ndiff(...)
for line in diff:
    code = line[0]  # The diff prefix
    print code,
    if code == '?':
        fld, offset = align(lastline, line[2:])
        for f in range(fld):
            print "%-12s" % '',
        print ' '*offset + '^'
    else:
        fields = line[2:].rstrip('\r\n').split(',')
        for f in fields:
            print "%-12s" % f,
        print
        lastline = line[2:]
```

Be warned that the only reliable way to parse CSV files is to use the `csv` module (or a robust alternative); but getting it to play well with the diff format (in *full* generality) would be a bit of a headache. If you're mainly interested in readability and your CSV isn't too gnarly, you can probably live with an occasional mix-up.