# csv file comparing differences

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv file (    ) I can get it to print out the the list with the totals summed up from the csv files. i use this code:

```
 import csv 
 import difflib

 file  = open('test1.csv',"rb") #Open CSV File in Read Mode 
 reader = csv.reader(file)      #Create reader object which iterates over lines 

 class Object:                   #Object to store unique data 
  def __init__(self, name, produce, amount): 
    self.name = name 
    self.produce = produce 
    self.amount = amount 

 rownum = 0 #Row Number currently iterating over 
 list = []  #List to store objects 

 def checkList(name, produce, amount): 

 for object in list:  #Iterate through list         
    if object.name == name and object.produce == produce:  #Check if name and produce        combination exists 
        object.amount += int(amount) #If it does add to amount variable and break out 
        return 

newObject = Object(name, produce, int(amount)) #Create a new object with new name, produce, and amount 
list.append(newObject)  #Add to list and break out 


 for row in reader:  #Iterate through all the rows 
  if rownum == 0:  #Store header row seperately to not get confused 
    header = row 
else: 
    name = row[0]  #Store name 
    produce = row[1]  #Store produce 
    amount = row[2]  #Store amount 

    if len(list) == 0:  #Default case if list = 0 
        newObject = Object(name, produce, int(amount)) 
        list.append(newObject) 
    else:  #If not... 
        checkList(name, produce, amount) 


rownum += 1 

 for each in list: 
  file1 =  each.name, each.produce, each.amount #END OF FILE 1


 file  = open('test2.csv',"rb") #Open CSV File in Read Mode 
 reader = csv.reader(file)      #Create reader object which iterates over lines 

 class Object:                   #Object to store unique data 
  def __init__(self, name, produce, amount): 
    self.name = name 
    self.produce = produce 
    self.amount = amount 

 rownum = 0 #Row Number currently iterating over 
 list = []  #List to store objects 

 def checkList(name, produce, amount): 

  for object in list:  #Iterate through list         
    if object.name == name and object.produce == produce:  #Check if name and produce    combination exists 
        object.amount += int(amount) #If it does add to amount variable and break out 
        return 

newObject = Object(name, produce, int(amount)) #Create a new object with new name, produce, and amount 
list.append(newObject)  #Add to list and break out 


 for row in reader:  #Iterate through all the rows 
  if rownum == 0:  #Store header row seperately to not get confused 
    header = row 
else: 
    name = row[0]  #Store name 
    produce = row[1]  #Store produce 
    amount = row[2]  #Store amount 

    if len(list) == 0:  #Default case if list = 0 
        newObject = Object(name, produce, int(amount)) 
        list.append(newObject) 
    else:  #If not... 
        checkList(name, produce, amount) 


rownum += 1 

 for each in list: 
   file2 = each.name, each.produce, each.amount #END OF FILE 2
```

All this works fine, I provided it just so you can see what I am doing.

So now I need to get the difference between the two new files I created. this is where I ger stuck; I tried this but no luck

```
 diff=difflib.ndiff('file1',"rb"), ('file2',"rb")
 try:
    while 1:
        print diff.next(),

 except:
     pass
```

I need the difference between the two new files to be generated so I can see the difference any suggustions? when i run it I get no errors, but no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Given your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110253/difflib-python-formating), it would seem that you should already know what is wrong.

Firstly you need to use the correct number of brackets.

```
diff = difflib.ndiff(('file1', 'rb'), ('file2', 'rb'))
```

But this is still incorrect because [difflib.ndiff](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff) requires two lists of strings, not the names and modes of unopened files. You need to read the contents of the files into a list of lines.

```
a = open('file1', 'rb').read().splitlines()
b = open('file2', 'rb').read().splitlines()

for diff in difflib.ndiff(a, b):
    print diff
```

Comment: do I still leave file1 =  each.name, each.produce, each.amount to call each file? I get an error when I try to run the code you put? Sorry still learning

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Test_energy", line 94, in <module>
    a = open('file1', 'rb').read().splitlines()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file1'

Comment: My earlier question I can get when compareing test one to test 2, but after I run the part of the code that takes all the different products and sums them together, and I try to run the difference I couldn't get it to work

Comment: If "file1" doesn't exist, how do you propose to read it? Your files look like they should be named "test1.csv" and "test2.csv". Try using the names of the actual files.

Comment: Ok I am proabably asking this wrong in the first part of the code, up until the #END OF FILE 1. How do I make that the new file I want to read in the ndiff?

Comment: Also, the large blob of code does not create any files. It opens 2 files in read mode and then repeatedly assigns to a tuple `(each.name, each.produce, each.amount)` to it. You need to either write each row out to files and then run `ndiff` over them, or construct the lists of strings required by `ndiff` and use them. As it is your code seems only to create two tuples: `file1` and `file2`

Comment: what is the best way to write them out to files? sorry I know probably a stupid question but I can figure it out. been trying and can't get it